# IntelliJ: UI Designer Documentation/Tutorial

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've enabled the UI Designer plugin in IntelliJ 9 (ultimate edition).  I've found some old flash [tutorial](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/training/demos.html#JavaDevelopment) that doesn't really show too much and is based on IntelliJ 6(!).  Is there any documentation or tutorials available that might go through a swing app using the UI Designer that is a little more recent and/or complicated than the old IntelliJ 6 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI Designer didn't change much since IDEA 6. I'd start with the built-in help system or its [online copy](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/designing-gui-major-steps.html).

Comment: A bit of a maze to navigate and doesn't really explain things well but I guess that's the best that I've seen out there.  I'll just have to keep plugging away and get the hang of it eventually.  Thanks!

Comment: I have Intellij IDEA 10.5, but that ancient GUI Designer demo is still  here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/training/demos/GUI_Designer/GUI_Designer.html